# using inputted values in a worksheet to reference different worksheets vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro in excel that takes cell values from one tab and creates a reference to these values as worksheets in vba.

An example of a worksheet list would be the following (could be longer or shorter in length):

```
sheet1
sheet2
sheet3
...
```

I have been able to store this in an array using the code below. With this array I would like to take these stored values and use them to reference worksheets as could be done manually as in the following.

```
ws1= wb.Sheets("sheet1")
ws(i)= wb.Sheets("ws(i)")
```

Any help to solve this or recommending a different approach would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, M

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsInputsList As Worksheet
Set wsInputsList = wb.Sheets("InputsTab")

Dim lastrowInputs As Long
lastrowInputs = wsInputsList.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While i < lastrowInputs
Dim ws(1 To 50) As Variant
ws(i) = wsInputsList.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: `Set ws(i) = wb.Sheets(wsInputsList.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Williams gave you the answer

Here I give you some more suggestions

code 1

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetSheetList()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsInputsList As Worksheet: Set wsInputsList = wb.Sheets("InputsTab")

    Dim lastrowInputs As Long, i As Long
    lastrowInputs = wsInputsList.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim ws(1 To lastrowInputs) As Worksheet 'dim your array only once
    For i = 1 To lastrowInputs
        Set ws(i) = wb.Sheets(wsInputsList.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next

End Sub
```

where

- moved array dimming outside the loop so as not to dim it `lastrowInputs` times…
- used a `For … Next` loop which fist more your case (does what you need, does it clearly and in less stataments)

but this kind of sheets listing is prone to some drawbacks, like having a name in the list that is no more actual. For which case you could consider

Code 2

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetSheetList2()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsInputsList As Worksheet: Set wsInputsList = wb.Sheets("InputsTab")

    Dim shtName As String
    Dim lastrowInputs As Long, i As Long, nshts As Long

    lastrowInputs = wsInputsList.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim ws(1 To lastrowInputs) As Worksheet 'dim your array only once

    For i = 1 To lastrowInputs
        shtName = wsInputsList.Cells(i, 1).Value ' store current "possible" sheet name
        If IsSheetThere(wb, shtName) Then  ' if current "possible" sheet name is an "actual" one
            nshts = nshts + 1 ' update sheet names found
            Set ws(nshts) = wb.Sheets(shtName) ' update sheets array
        End If
    Next
    If nshts < lastrowInputs Then ReDim Preserve ws(1 To nshts) As Worksheet 'redim your array to the actual number of items stored, if needed

End Sub
```

And yet ther's a chance your sheet names list in "InputsTab" isn't exhaustive…

As you see, keeping and using such a list can be much more difficult than it might seem at the beginning: it's a matter of focusing on what you really need and why

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm having some trouble running this getting a Compile error: Sub or Function not defined for the following line If IsSheetThere(wb, shtName) Then ' if current "possible" sheet name is an "actual" one